# Hibernate compare with empty List?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, grails, hql

I have the following Hibernate HQL query:

```
 def query = 
 """
select i from Item
where i not in :someItemList
 """

 def items = Item.executeQuery(query, [someItemList: someItemList])
```

In my query someItemList is a list of Item objects. This query works fine if someItemList is not empty. Hibernate raises an exception in case the list is empty.

Is there a way to modify this query that it also works with the empty someItemList?

Comment: Can you show how you are using it?

Comment: Also, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450400/hql-where-in-for-empty-list-crashes

Comment: Have you tried: `... and count(:someItemList) > 0`?

Comment: Change the query string depending if someItemList is empty or not.

Comment: @ShadowCreeper can you please post an answer to your comment?

Comment: @confile I never tested it, it was only a question about a theory. If it worked, awesome! However I think the clean answer is just to *not* run the query if `someItemList.isEmpty()`.

Comment: @ShadowCreeper the result is the same exception even when use count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def someItemList = ['Example'] //empty in cases    

def query = 
 """
select i from Item ${someItemList ? ' where i not in (:someItemList)' : ''}
 """

def items = someItemList ? Item.executeQuery(query, [someItemList: someItemList])
                         : Item.executeQuery(query)

//or try
def items = Item.executeQuery(query, 
                            someItemList ? [someItemList:someItemList] : [:])
```

Using GString.

Comment: I get the error: Parameter someItemList does not exist as a named parameter in query, in case the someItemList is empty. How to fix that?

Comment: Same would apply for the query, see update. Not that much DRY. With the `if` block as shown in the other answer it will simpler. @confile

Answer (score 2):

Just verify if the list is empty before creating the query.

```
if (someItemList.isEmpty()) {
   select i from Item    //your query
} else {
   select i from Item
   where i not in :someItemList   //your query here
}
```

Comment: Can it be done within the HQL query as well?

Comment: As far as I know if u try to use the query as you want, it will always complain when the list is empty. I had this problem before and I have solved it by checking for empty before creating the query...