# Hibernate NOT IN empty list evaluates to false

Tags: hibernate

I have the following hibernate query:

```java
public long countHouseBoats(HouseBoat houseBoat, Type type, List<Long> excludedIds) {
   TypedQuery<Long> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(o) FROM AquaticCity o " +
       "WHERE o.houseBoat = :houseBoat " +
       "AND o.chimneyType = :chimneyType " +
       "AND o.keel.manufacturer.id NOT IN (:excludedIds) " +
       "AND o.type.name IN (:types)", Long.class);
   query.setParameter("houseBoat", houseBoat);
   query.setParameter("chimneyType", ChimneyType.REGULAR);
   query.setParameter("excludedIds", excludedIds);
   query.setParameter("types", toStringList(List.of(type)));
   return query.getSingleResult();
}
```

It works as I expect if `excludedIds` is not empty. If it is empty then it is as though `NOT IN <emptyList>` evaluates to `false` rather than always evaluating to `true` as one would expect.

I am out of ideas why this happens. I have read around and some [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450400/hql-where-in-for-empty-list-crashes) exists, but they are not really the same.

I'm about to resort to the obvious ugly workaround of checking if the list is empty and if it is, build the query without the `excludedIds` check.

Comment: What hibernate version do you use? What database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's explained in the hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-in-predicate):

> The list of values can come from a number of different sources. In the `constructor_expression` and `collection_valued_input_parameter`, *the list of values must not be empty; it must contain at least one value.*

But actually the behavior related to in predicate processing was changed under [HHH-8901](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8901). See additional details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63658492/6277104). And probably that is why you get what you get.